# Leaflet OS Mastermap raster tile layer max zoom level 14?

Tags: leaflet, os-mastermap

I have a leaflet map displaying OS premium raster tile service Leisure_27700 ZXY. I would like the max zoom level to be 14. It worked perfectly down to zoom level 13. I tried to extend it to zoom level  14 and added resolution “0.054688” however when you click onto level 14 the map initially displays and then is immediately overwritten by grey tiles.

I realise the OS tech documents refer to zoom levels 0-13 but surely this can be over written?

https://osdatahub.os.uk/docs/wmts/technicalSpecification

My code is as follows :

```
var apiKey = ' /*a fucntioning api key*/ ';

    var serviceUrl = 'https://api.os.uk/maps/raster/v1/zxy';
    //variables for os postcode serach 
  var apiKey2 = '/*a fucntioning api key*/ ';

    var nameServiceUrl = 'https://api.os.uk/search/names/v1',
        tileServiceUrl = 'https://api.os.uk/maps/raster/v1/zxy';




     // Setup the EPSG:27700 (British National Grid) projection.
    var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:27700', '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs', {
        resolutions: [ 896.0, 448.0, 224.0, 112.0, 56.0, 28.0, 14.0, 7.0, 3.5, 1.75, 0.875, 0.4375, 0.21875, 0.109375, 0.054688, ],
        origin: [ -238375.0, 1376256.0 ]
    });
   

    // Instantiate a tile layer object for the Leisure style (displayed at zoom levels 0-9).
    var leisure = L.tileLayer(serviceUrl + '/Leisure_27700/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=' + apiKey, {
        maxZoom: 14
    });

    // Instantiate a tile layer object for the Road style (displayed at zoom levels 10-13).
    var road = L.tileLayer(serviceUrl + '/Road_27700/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=' + apiKey, {
        maxZoom: 14,
        minZoom: 10
    });

    // Transform coordinates.
    var transformCoords = function(arr) {
        return proj4('EPSG:27700', 'EPSG:4326', arr).reverse();
    };

    // Initialize the map.
    var mapOptions = {
        crs: crs,
        layers: [ leisure, road ],
        minZoom: 0,
        maxZoom: 14,
        center: transformCoords([ 247692 , 55333]), // wets humble =transformCoords([ 516710, 151737]),
        zoom: 10,
        maxBounds: [
            transformCoords([ -238375.0, 0.0 ]),
            transformCoords([ 900000.0, 1376256.0 ])
        ],
        attributionControl: false
    };


    var map = L.map('map', mapOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

seems the answer is to use maxNativeZoom like so:

```
var leisure = L.tileLayer(serviceUrl + '/Leisure_27700/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=' + apiKey, {
        maxZoom: 14,
        maxNativeZoom: 13
```